# Curl error in my server

Tags: curl

I am getting error like below in my server but in local it's working fine how can i increased the time in curl to but it's showing same error.

```
Curl error: Connection timed out after 2001 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-m, --max-time <seconds>
Maximum  time  in  seconds that you allow the whole operation to
take.  This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from  hang‐
ing  for  hours due to slow networks or links going down.  Since
7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values, but the actual time‐
out will decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases
in decimal precision.  See also the --connect-timeout option.

If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
```

Comment: how can i increase the time?I need to increase in server or in curl itself?

Comment: I will help if you explain how you actually are using curl.. Update your question with the relevant info

Answer (score 0):

Curl has a [config file](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline-configfile.html), .curlrc. Check whether the `connect-timeout` option has been set there.

> The default config file is checked for in the following places in this
>   order:
>
> 1. curl tries to find the "home directory": It first checks for the CURL_HOME and then the HOME environment variables. Failing that, it
>      uses getpwuid() on Unix-like systems (which returns the home directory
>      given the current user in your system). On Windows, it then checks for
>      the APPDATA variable, or as a last resort the
>      '%USERPROFILE%\Application Data'.
> 2. On Windows, if there is no _curlrc file in the home directory, it checks for one in the same directory the curl executable is placed. On
>      Unix-like systems, it will simply try to load .curlrc from the
>      determined home directory.